# Replace multiple words with the same pattern in one command (Atom Editor)

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm using Atom editor for my project and want to change some text occurrences in it with the same pattern in one command.
As a simple example, say that I have the following string literals occurrences : `"hello", "bye", "cow"`. I want to remove the double quotes from each string, then add the prefix `SomeType::` to each and then wrap each with curly brackets. That means, replace `"hello"` with `{SomeType::hello}`and same for the other strings.

It is obvious you can do it with 3 `Find And Replace` commands in Atom.
But can you do it with one command (using regex)?

Comment: Which regex have you tried? do you want to replace specific words or anything between quotes?

Answer (score 0):

```
Find: "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
Replace All: {SomeType::$1}
```